# GetElementID of dynamically assigned object

Tags: javascript

My javascript function accepts a parameter which changes dynamically. I want to get it's dynamically generated ClientID as i m using a server control.

```
function myfun(btn){

   var id=btn.name+"1";
   document.getElementByID('<%"+id+".ClientID%>')  --something like this
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, because you want to mixure service side with client side code... So you have to use

```
document.getElementByID('<%btnId.ClientID%>')
```

or

```
document.getElementByID('btnId')
```

but since you mention that you want to find server controls (asp.net buttons?) you should use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add something into your server side code like this: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Page, "var myControlsID=" + btnId.ClientID, true);`

Though it is legal to have those <%= %> inline in the page I've found it to cause problems in several cases. Avoid it if you can.